# ui select placeholder text with search disabled

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

I am using angular ui-select Selectize Theme. I want to disable search but would like to show place holder text so that user know what is this select field is used for. 
I tried modifying selectize/match.tpl.html to

```
<div ng-hide=\"($select.open || $select.isEmpty())\" class=\"ui-select-match\" ng-transclude=\"\">{{$select.placeholder}}</div>
```

But this always rending as

```
<div ng-hide="($select.open || $select.isEmpty())" class="ui-select-match ng-hide" ng-transclude="" placeholder="Select or search a country in the list..."><span class="ng-binding ng-scope"></span></div>
```

How to modify template to show place holder text in Span/Div and show it by default. 
Or is there any better way to disable search and show placeholder text ?

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LJSq4JNIK2iOTdjJ57oJ?p=preview)

i have created a wrapper directive over this and modifying inside a link line below

```
  angular.element(angular.element($element[0])).find('span').text($scope.placeholder)
```

and again in controller

```
 angular.element(angular.element($element[0])).find('span').text(scope.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a wrapper directive around this, updated match template like below, and using search-enable = false

`$templateCache.put("selectize/match.tpl.html","<div  class=\"ui-select-match\" ng-transclude=\"\"></div>");`

using "link" in wrapper directive i am updating above template with palceholder text

```
  angular.element(angular.element($element[0])).find('span').text($scope.placeholder)
```

using controller in wrapper directive, updating selected string

```
 angular.element(angular.element($element[0])).find('span').text(scope.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified select.tpl.html like below

```
$templateCache.put("selectize/select.tpl.html","<div class=\"selectize-control single\"><div class=\"selectize-input\" ng-class=\"{\'focus\': $select.open, \'disabled\': $select.disabled, \'selectize-focus\' : $select.focus}\" ng-click=\"$select.activate()\"><div class=\"ui-select-match\"></div><div class=\"ui-select-placeholder\" ng-hide=\"!$select.isEmpty()\">{{$select.placeholder}}</div><input type=\"text\" autocomplete=\"off\"  tabindex=\"-1\" class=\"ui-select-search ui-select-toggle\" ng-click=\"$select.toggle($event)\" placeholder=\"{{$select.placeholder}}\" readonly ng-model=\"$select.search\" ng-hide=\"!$select.searchEnabled || ($select.selected && !$select.open)\" ng-disabled=\"$select.disabled\"></div><div class=\"ui-select-choices\"></div></div>");}]);
```

Which adds a div with placeholder when selection is empty. Else it will be hidden